# Even numbers in Pascal's triangle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

Basically i've been looking at Pascal's triangle and been wondering how it represents Sierpinski's triangle once the even numbers are shaded. Once I rewrote the triangle in terms of C I observed that 2C1 is an even number and 4C1/4C2/4C3. However, I cannot postulate a reasonable statement which describes the rational behind the connection of Pascal's and Sierpinski's triangles.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem, which describes a trick well known to algebraic topologists for calculating binomial coefficients modulo a prime $p$. When you apply this trick with $p =2$, the connection with the Sierpinski triangle should begin to make sense.